# Struggling with performance in a Laravel Database access

Tags: php, laravel

I am transfering some older code that runs quite fast over into a laravel project, and now the queries are responding very slowly.  I have been pounding away at this all day and have not been able to figure out what the problem is.

the problem is in the for loop, it slows to a crawl if it has to run through many users.

I am a fairly new coder, so I expect I am missing something obivous.

```
public function generateGraphDataByCategory($id,$days){
    $days = (int)$days;
    $catids=array($id);
    //get the sub categories assoticated with catID
    $newcatids = $catids;
    foreach ($catids AS $catid) {
        $newcatids = array_merge($newcatids, self::SubcategoryList($catid));
    }

    //format in variable from the array of category ID's
    $in = implode(", ", $newcatids);

    $starttime = time() - 60*60*24*$days;

    $endtime = time();

    // get number of views for each user





     $results1 = DB::Select("SELECT
            UH.UserID, SUM(UH.Views) AS Views
            FROM UserHistory UH
                LEFT JOIN Content C ON UH.ContentID = C.ID
            WHERE
                UH.Timestamp >= '1466455886'
                AND UH.Timestamp <= '1467751886'
                AND (C.Cat1 IN (41) OR C.Cat2 IN (41) OR C.Cat3 IN     (41))   
                AND C.members_only = 2

            GROUP BY UH.UserID");

   $totals = array(
    0 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0
);


//foreach user figure out the percentage and update totals
for ($index=0;$index<count($results1);$index++){
  $uh=$results1[$index];
  $results2 = DB::select("SELECT
                SUM(UH.Views) AS views
                FROM UserHistory UH
                    LEFT JOIN Content C ON UH.ContentID = C.ID
                WHERE UH.Timestamp >= '$starttime'
                    AND UH.Timestamp <= '$endtime'
                    AND C.members_only = 2
                    AND UH.UserID = 8");


   $uhtotal = $results2[0]->views;
   $perc = $uh->Views / $uhtotal;

  if ($perc >= 0.9) {
        $totals[0]++;
    }
    if ($perc >= 0.75) {
        $totals[1]++;
    }
    if ($perc >= 0.5) {
        $totals[2]++;
    }
    if ($perc >= 0.25) {
        $totals[3]++;
    }
    if ($perc >= 0.10) {
        $totals[4]++;
    }
    if ($perc >= 0) {
        $totals[5]++;
        }


    }



    return $totals;
  }
```

Comment: fyi: that repeated `or` could simply be `and 41 in (c.cat1, c.cat2, c.cat3)`. have you tried an `explain` of that query in the mysql client to see what the execution plan will be?

Comment: into  cycle you repeatedly refer to the database
This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163777/best-approach-to-select-most-viewed-posts-from-last-n-hours/38163954#38163954